# Error with Gradle using VS Code: "Could not run build action using Gradle distribution"

Tags: java, android, gradle, visual-studio-code

I've started getting the following error message when opening an existing Gradle project in VS Code after upgrading the Gradle installation on my computer:

> Could not run build action using Gradle distribution
> 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5.1-bin.zip').

I've found similar questions floating around with different version numbers, such as:
[Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.9-bin.zip'.](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/755)